# MySQL Create Function Fails With Error 1064

Tags: mysql, create-function

I have a function on my production server running MySQL v5.5.8 that executes with no problem.

When I try to create the same function on my test server running MySQL v5.5.9 the create fails with an error 1064.  Can someone please explain why it is ok on one server but not on the other?  Why MySQL returns such vague and unhelpful messages I'll never know!!!

The create is:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `CheckProjType` (type INT, cost BIGINT ) 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
    CHARSET latin1
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE rtn VARCHAR(50);
    IF type = 5 THEN SET rtn = 'New Maint';
    ELSE
      IF type = 4 THEN SET rtn = 'Ongoing Maintenance';
      ELSE
        IF type = 3 THEN SET rtn = 'New Development';
        else
          IF cost > 1000000000 THEN SET rtn = 'New Expansion';
          else
            IF cost > 250000000 THEN SET rtn = 'Major Improvement';
            ELSE
              IF cost > 25000000 THEN SET rtn = 'Major Development';
              ELSE
                 SET rtn = 'Small Improvement';
              END IF;
            END IF;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END IF;
    END IF;

  RETURN rtn;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '' at line 6

SQL Statement:

CREATE FUNCTION `CheckProjType` (type INT, cost BIGINT ) 

    RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 

    CHARSET latin1

    NO SQL

BEGIN

    DECLARE rtn VARCHAR(50)
```

Comment: Try with `DELIMITER //` Seems to be working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca18e).

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Your fiddle is using MySQL 5.5.30, which doesn't apply to either of the OP's target environments.